# How to enforce an Axis Client to use TLSv1.2 protocol

Tags: ssl, axis, webservices-client, tls1.2

A third party our application is integrate with has recently made changes in their security level protocols. In short, My Axis client should now send calls using TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2.
I have seen other posts regarding this, with some good ideas:

1. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142654/force-axis-client-to-use-tls)
2. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651684/axis-securesocketfactory-setting-the-constructor-attributes).

After making those changes in code, I have triggered the calls again,
I have used a snipping tool to monitor the sent package, and I still see in the SSL layer that the protocol being used is TLSv1.

[the packet snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htrRE.jpg)

what am I doing wrong here?

this is how I set my new SocketSecureFactory:

```
AxisProperties.setProperty("axis.socketSecureFactory", MyTLSSocketSecureFactory.class.getName());
```

whereas MyTLSSocketSecureFactory is:

```
public class MyTLSSocketSecureFactory extends JSSESocketFactory {
    public MyTLSSocketSecureFactory(Hashtable attributes) {
        super(attributes);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket create(String host,int port,   StringBuffer otherHeaders,BooleanHolder useFullURL)
              throws Exception{
        Socket s = super.create(host, port, otherHeaders, useFullURL);
        ((SSLSocket)s).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"});
        return s;
    }
}
```

would really appreciate any comments,
thanks.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem - the 3'rd party server started to accept only TLS 1.1 or 1.2 connections since last night without prior notification.
I'm using JDK 6 u 35, Axis 1.4. Tried with the below described solution but it doesn't make any difference, tshark still says I'm going out with TLSv1:  TLSv1 75 Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Handshake Failure)

Answer (score 8):

In your MyTLSSocketSecureFactory class, you need create your own SSLContext instance and then get the sslFactory from the context.

Override the initFactory() method, and somethings like:

```
initFactory() {
  SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
  context.init(null, null, null);
  sslFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
}
```

Comment: This works well. Just need to change the SSLContext.getInstance("TSLv1.2"); "TSL" to TLS..

Answer (score 3):

You can also just change the default SSLContext

```
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
    sslContext.init(null, null, null);
    SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

See also https://github.com/unkascrack/axis-ssl they introduce a SSLClientAxisEngineConfig EngineConfiguration implementation to enable TLS.