# Unable to connect webservice after the server upgraded to support only TLS V1.1

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, tls1.2

A webservice client was written using apache axis 1.4 and it was working until the SSLv3 is upgraded to TLSv1.1 in the serverside. After the TLSv1.1 upgrade in the serverside, webservice stopped working. Our client was using Java 1.6, then upgraded to java 1.7 to support TLSv1.1. But still our client is not working.

Comment: See [Enable TLS 1.1 and 1.2 for Clients on Java 7](http://superuser.com/questions/747377/enable-tls-1-1-and-1-2-for-clients-on-java-7)

Comment: Or move to Java 8 where it is enabled by default.  In one case, I had Java 7 and couldn't upgrade due to the OS level.  I was unable to get those methods to work, and I ended up having to put some code in to add it via the SSLContext.  Java 8 works out of the box, and if you can, is the best solution.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I have no option to move to Java 8. My Linux server supports openssl 0.9.8 which does not support TLS v1.1 and TLS 1.2. I tried the way suggested by  Steffen Ullrich, but it is not working. I would like to know how we can make it work using some code. If the OS does not support TLS, Please tell me what is the possible work around

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180289/how-to-enforce-an-axis-client-to-use-tlsv1-2-protocol

Comment: Thank you very much Mike. I used that code and it is working with some tweak. After little analysis, we found that the server is disconnecting the connection while handshaking. The handshake is happening inside the create method of JSSESocketFactory class. We copied the create method  in MyTLSSocketSecureFactory  and enabled TLSv1.1 & TLSv1.2. Then it is working good.